# Creating a tuple out of *args

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension, args, iterable-unpacking

I've tried, but I can't figure this out so far.
I want to create a list of tuples, each one built out of dictionary values:

```
my_list = [(x['field1'], x['field2']) for x in my_dict]
```

But the issue is that I want to do this inside a function, passing the fields I want to get to *args:

```
my_func('field1', 'field2')
```

How can I build the first list comprehension out of the *args list?

Thanks!

I'll try to clarify:

Briefly, what I want to do is map this:

```
my_func('field1', 'field2')
```

To this:

```
tuple(x['field1'], x['field2'])
```

Which will be a statement inside my_func(*args)

Comment: Not so clear what you want to do. Can you give an example (or two) with the input/output you want?

Comment: Unclear ... what is `my_dict` in this ... a list of dictionaries?  Are you wanting to get a different field from each element of `my_dict`?

Comment: Like what exactly are you asking? Creating tuples from function arguments? So you want function which will return tuple ?

Comment: `*args` **already creates a tuple** - `args`, inside the function, would be `('field1', 'field2')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `tuple` by doing another comprehension over the `args`:

```
def my_func(*args):
    return [tuple(x[arg] for arg in args) for x in my_dict]
```

However this assumes that your `my_dict` is a global variable. But now you can call it like you specified with `my_func('field1', 'field2')`.

I would advise to add the dictionary to the function definition:

```
def my_func(my_dict, *args):
    return [tuple(x[arg] for arg in args) for x in my_dict]
```

and call it as `my_func(my_dict, 'field1', 'field2')`

Comment: It's ok, in fact the function is more complex, and includes the dictionary. I made it simpler so the question is clearer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Simply refer to those arguments as normal:

```
def f(d, a, b):
    return [(x[a], x[b]) for x in d]

result = f(my_dict, 'field1', 'field2')
```